# NestJS TypeORM mongodb find in an array column does not work

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, typeorm

so I'm working on a project with NestJs and TypeORM with mongodb. Earlier we was working with express and mongoose and to find results in an array column we was using something like this :

```
        Event.find({
                'teachers': _id
            })
```

and now when we migrated to the new Nest backend with TypeORM we are using this :

```
        this.eventRepository.find({
                where: {
                    'teachers': _id
                }
            });
```

but this isn't working. What's weird is that all the queries that we was using with mongoose do work except for this. I tried to work with mongoose with NestJS and this did work so there's no problem with function parameters or anything.

Now I will post how our event entity looks like so that you can have an idea :

```
@Entity('events')
export class Event{
    
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    public _id: ObjectID;

    @Column()
    public title :string;

    @Column()
    public teachers: string[];
//the rest with getters and setters.
```

It would be great if someone can show me if I'm doing something wrong or there's someway else to do it or it is a bug with TypeORM that I should report.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have an entity class called: `Teacher` with an `_id` field as such:

```
 @ObjectIdColumn()
    public _id: ObjectID;
```

In your `Event` entity class, you should change teachers from type `string[]` to `ObjectID[]` like this:

```
 @Column()
    public teachers: ObjectID[];
```

Finally, your query should be as follows:

```
 this.eventRepository.find({
    where: {
        'teachers._id': { $eq: _id }
    }
 });
```